# Format address string properly

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-formatting

I'm querying a database which returns intersection addresses in all caps. I want to make it so the address is formatted as one would write it.

e.g. if it returns `PINEHURST WAY NE & NE 115TH ST`, it should be formatted as `Pinehurst Way NE & NE 115th St`. I've tried using the `capitalizedString` method for `NSString` but that capitalizes every word (e.g. `Pinehurst Way Ne & 115Th St`).

Here's my code:
`adStr = [adStr capitalizedString];`

Is there any way I can format it the way I want it to?

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in NSString `capitalizeAsOneWouldWriteAnAddress` method that magically understands the logic of capitalizing the words of an address in the way you are trying to achieve. You will therefore have to achieve it manually. For example, you will have to look for compass directions such as "NE" and "SW" and make them (or keep them) all caps. And you will have to look for ordinals such as "115th" (basically, any word that starts with a digit - NSRegularExpression will come in handy here) and make sure the letters are lowercase.

You might want to look into NSLinguisticTagger to see whether it can help you tag the pieces of the address meaningfully, but I doubt that it can.

Comment: I'm aware that there is no method for it. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Well then I'm afraid it's not evident to me what the question _is_. I did describe the sort of thing you're going to have to do. What's the trouble? Do you not find the documentation on the methods for how to search a string?

Comment: I was just commenting on your remark at the beginning of your answer. I just felt it was unnecessary.

Comment: I don't see why. There _might_ have been something like this. It isn't an unreasonable notion at all. After all, there are methods (associated with Map Kit, for example) that do return a properly formatted address.

Comment: And again, if you are aware that there is no such method, then I don't see what the question is. Are you just trying to convince yourself that you will have to "do it yourself"? Okay, I'm trying to help convince you. It's a pain but there it is.

Comment: What methods in Map Kit return a properly formatted address?

Comment: Like when you obtain an address using reverse geocoding. But I'm afraid that's not going to help you here. The trouble is that you already _have_ your address as a string. It's now a purely string-formatting problem.

Comment: I added my own answer which works for me. Please check it out and let me now if I can improve it. Don't take what I said with offense, I appreciate your help.

Comment: No offense taken. But I _still_ don't understand the point of your question. You knew perfectly well what to do. Did you need permission?

Comment: There's plenty of little objective-c tricks I learn about everyday. Perhaps maybe some one knew of one which would assist my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
adStr = [adStr capitalizedString];

if ([string rangeOfString:@" Ne "].location != NSNotFound) {
    adStr = [adStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" Ne " withString:@" NE "];  
}
```

Try putting NE, SE, SW, etc into a array and nest the if statement in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method I used:

```
-(NSString *)formattedAdd:(NSString *)address {
    //Start with fresh capitalized string.
    address = [address capitalizedString];
    //Format directions properly.
    NSArray *directions = @[@"Ne", @"Se", @"Sw", @"Nw"];
    for (NSString *direc in directions) {
        if ([address rangeOfString:direc options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
            address = [address stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:direc withString:[direc uppercaseString]];
        }
    }
    //Create regexes for street and numerical street names
    NSRegularExpressionOptions regexOptions = NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive;
    NSString *pattern = @"[0-9]\\w+";
    NSString *patterntwo = @"\\s(?:St|Ave|Pl)";

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:regexOptions error:nil];
    NSRegularExpression *regextwo = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:patterntwo options:regexOptions error:nil];

    //Fix numerical street names.
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:address options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, address.length)];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *re in matches) {
        NSString *numSt = [address substringWithRange:re.range];
        address = [address stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:re.range withString:[numSt lowercaseString]];
    }
    //Fix "St" with "St., Ave with Ave., etc."
    NSArray *matchestwo = [regextwo matchesInString:address options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, address.length)];
    NSMutableString *adMut = [address mutableCopy];
    int count = 0;
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *re in matchestwo) {
        int index = (int)re.range.location + (int)re.range.length;
        [adMut insertString:@"." atIndex:index + (count == 1 ? 1:0];
        count++;
    }
    address = [adMut copy];
    return address;
}
```